# mkdir: cannot create directory : Permission denied when trying to read a file in a docker container

Tags: docker, file-permissions

Hey so I'm trying to debug why a container won't build or rather fails to build and so when I run `docker run -it intermediateBuildHash bash` and navigate to a service's log file which is stored in `/val/log/service` anytime I try to cat, tail, head, any type of read command it returns `mkdir: cannot create directory : Permission denied`  ... why? I'm trying to read a file not create a directory.  This leads me to believe this may the source of my issues building the container.  Is it maybe some sort of permission issue?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Running latest Arch and Docker on an ubuntu based image.

Comment: Share you `Dockerfile`

Comment: Right, so there is a chance that you may not even be able to recreate the issue. For more context :  https://github.com/ONLYOFFICE/Docker-DocumentServer/issues/386 and the dockerfile I'm using : https://pastebin.com/eQ57eh85 it's basically the original dockerfile but broken up into more RUN commands so that I can more accurately debug/find the issue.  Once it fails I take the last hash and use `docker commit $lasthash debug` then `docker run -it debug bash` and when I'm inside the container that's when the issue arises.

Comment: The tl;dr of the context is that  this seems to only happen inside containers of ONLYOFFICE/Docker-DocumentServer on certain machines running Arch linux.